# Is it possible to assign public IP to Hyper-V VM which is in Azure VM?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, hyper-v

I have Azure VM with enabled Hyper-V feature. Azure VM has two public IPs. So the question is how to assign public IP to Hyper-V VM? Is it possible to propagate one of the public IPs of Azure VM to Hyper-V VM? Is it possible to expose Hyper-V VM to the outer world with its own public IP? Or maybe there are some other options? Or maybe there is a short answer to this question which is "definitely not possible" and you could share some link to the documentation which proves it and explains why?

Comment: Does this issue be fixed on your side?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to build Hyper-V nested VM with multiple public IP addresses. You could work through [this blog](https://gooddealmart.ca/build-hyper-v-nested-vm-with-multiple-public-ip-addresses-at-azure-azure-mvpbuzz-mvphour-firewall/) step by step.

> due to restrictions on the network fabric, it is not possible to
> create an external switch and give VMs direct access to the host’s
> physical network. A solution to this is to configure NAT so that VMs
> can access the Internet with the host NATed public IP and also routing
> to enable connectivity to other VMs in Azure.

For more references, read [here](https://azurecloudai.blog/2019/12/16/how-to-enable-internet-and-vnet-connectivity-for-nested-vms-in-azure/).